# Using Altair to generate an unstacked barplot with an already stacked data

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I created a DataFrame with stacked data, i.e., tested \in total.

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'],
  'total': [10, 15, 20],
  'tested': [0, 5, 10]
})

dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['date'])
```

I would like to plot a stacked bar plot with Altair. Since the `tested` column is already contained in the `total` column, I would expect a chart with the max values of the `total`, but the result shows the sum.

```py
alt.Chart(dfm).mark_bar().encode(
    x='date:O',
    y='value:Q',
    color='variable:O'
)
```

[image]

I know I can use pandas to create an `untested` column and generate the plot using `tested` and `untested` columns, but I would like to know if I can achieve this result without transforming the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an unstacked bar chart you can set `stack=False`:

```py
alt.Chart(dfm).mark_bar().encode(
    x='date:O',
    y=alt.Y('value:Q', stack=False),
    color='variable:O'
)
```

[image]

Note that it will always show the rightmost column on top (`tested` in the image above).